# Which ip is used when two net cards all can be used?

Tags: ip

There are two net cards in used status in my pc.

```
ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:3f:49:57:4b:d1
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e23f:49ff:fe57:4bd1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6068 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3780468 (3.6 MiB)  TX bytes:11800 (11.5 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:700 (700.0 B)  TX bytes:700 (700.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:5d:26:c1:10
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::221:5dff:fe26:c110/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1291 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5146 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:81917 (79.9 KiB)  TX bytes:992000 (968.7 KiB)
```

How to know which ip address is used when to connect to yahoo.com with my pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the default route with (mine looks like this):

```
$ ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev em0
10.0.0.0/24 dev em0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.120
```

That will tell you which device is being used and so which IP address. As for the IP address that yahoo.com will see, that depends on your connection via your ISP but a simple way is to use a simple web service such as http://whatismyipaddress.com/

For most cases this will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Linux will normally default to the connection over eth0 as the primary connection.  What it appears you have here is a wired connection (eth0 = ethernet wired connection), the lo which is always the return IP of your NIC (Loopback 127.0.0.1), and a wireless LAN connection (wlan0 = Wireless LAN connection).

Your wlan0 connection is only going to pass traffic when eth0 is not.  This is because while an ethernet cable is plugged into your computer (what I'm assuming is a laptop), it will temporarily disable your wireless connection from passing traffic.  If your computer were to pass traffic over both at the same time, there would be two issues I can think of off-hand:

1. You'd likely be passing broken traffic (consistent interruption of connection), and
2. You would likely hinder your home router's ability to interpret and properly route traffic; i.e. you would confuse your poor little mini-router.

The only way I could see both being in use at the same time would be in an environment where you were passing traffic to two different subnets, possibly through virtual machines.  For example, if your host connected to your router over RJ-45 (ethernet), but your virtual machine connected to your neighbor's network over Wi-Fi.

@Felix: you're not going to see a 10 address on a class C (home network) with a 192.168.0.0 subnet.